# How to put two layouts inside a relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to place two layouts on top of each other. I am using relative layouts and placing them inside a relative layout. But the problem is I am only getting one of the layouts displayed and that is the latter one.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom|center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dip"
        android:background="#00ACE7"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"  >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/telenor_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/telenor_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/telenor_logo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/telenor_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/telenor_logo" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/options"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:background="#00ACE7"
            android:src="@drawable/options" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#00ACE7"
            android:src="@drawable/settings" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dip"
        android:background="#B6B6B4"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:weightSum="1" 
        android:layout_below="@+android:id/relative_layout1" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this attribute to the following in the second relative layout

```
android:layout_below="@id/relativeLayout1"
```

So it would end up looking like this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dip"
    android:background="#B6B6B4"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:weightSum="1" 
    android:layout_below="@id/relativeLayout1">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, just as a quick note:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

(in API Level 8+) should be replaced by:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Comment: Yeah well I did that, but it's still showing just the latter layout.

Comment: Is it necessary for your to have a relative layout as a parent?  Have you considered making the parent a LinearLayout with two child relative layouts?

Comment: Yes I have and I have even tried it but it's still not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please change this `android:layout_below="@+android:id/relative_layout1"`with `android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"`  to set relativleayout1 on top of relativelayout2 
 [image: Screen Shot]